# How can I monitor "resources" during a snakemake workflow run?

Tags: snakemake

all.

I have a very large number of jobs, some of which are IO intensive. I am using a resource (http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html#resources) to limit the number of such jobs, but a proportion of them fail. It seems that over time, the number of submitted jobs seems to slowly decrease and I suspect that this might be due to resources not being freed after a job with a resource fails. I can try to put together a reproducible example, but I thought I would first ask if there is there a mechanism for monitoring "available" resources in a running workflow?

And, of course, any other suggestions for how to troubleshoot are appreciated.

Thanks,
Sean

Environment:

- Python3.5
- slurm cluster
- Snakemake 4.3.1

Comment: I think there are IO-related information in the output of the rule's `benchmark` section. But I think this information is only available after a given rule instance has completed.

Comment: @bli, I was thinking more about the "resources" tag that snakemake uses. This is not really directly related to what the job uses of compute resources, but a simple counter. I updated the question to reflect this specific issue.

Comment: You mean, you would like to monitor the formal "resources" thing that snakemake uses, because you suspect that there may be some of this not properly "released" ? That would be a bug in snakemake, I think. Or simply that some rule instances are stalled, or take too long, but then the real issue would not be in the formal snakemake "resources" thing.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that there may be a bug. Source code, here I come....